# Why is my GPU rendering so slowly?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have an AMD Radeon RX580 graphics card with an i7-7700K CPU. When I render an image - regardless of tile size - both the graphics card and the CPU render it quite slowly, but the GPU much slower. This is a surprise to me because I would have thought that my GPU, which I definitely have selected in settings, would be rendering much faster. I know it's not the fastest GPU but surely it can render a bloody donut in less than 2 minutes. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might be able to fix this? I'm pretty new to Blender, so I might have overlooked an apparently obvious solution. Thanks.

Comment: What is the tile size for the gpu?

Comment: It's 64x64, but I did change it up to a higher tile size (256x256), and it just took much longer to render a single larger tile.

Comment: Can you try reinstalling your gpu drivers and blender?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either... Now there are lines showing on my renders when I used my GPU. Is it possible the GPU is just crap?

Comment: Most likely the issue.